# interface custom preprocessor task in WP7 project compilation by modying the csproj file

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, xaml, preprocessor, csproj

I have a Visual Studio solution with 2 Windows Phone 7 projects. One is the main project, the other links its xaml pages from the first.

I try to modify the .csproj file of the second project in order to preprocess its linked pages by a custom task. My modifications are based upon the sample solution of [this blog post](http://www.softaware.at/Aktuelles/2013/04/03/Sharing-XAML-between-WPF-and-WinRT) :

Xaml pages are indeed processed by my custom task but the output files are not used in continuation of the compiling process. I guess this is the involved portion of code :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProcessedPages Include="@(Page->'%(Link)')" />
  <!-- Remove the original (linked) pages so that they are not compiled. -->
  <Page Remove="@(Page)" Condition="('%(Page.Link)' != '')" />
  <!-- Include the processed pages instead. -->
  <Page Include="@(ProcessedPages)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**How to modify it so MarkupCompilePass1 use output file of the PreprocessorTask task ?**

By the way, I don’t get what is the value of @(Page->'%(Link)') during compilation.

Compelete project file for reference :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="XamlPreprocessor.PreprocessorTask" AssemblyFile="C:\Users\Louis\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\XamlPreprocessor\XamlPreprocessor\bin\Debug\XamlPreprocessor.exe" />
  <PropertyGroup>
   <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
   <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
<ProductVersion>10.0.20506</ProductVersion>
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<ProjectGuid>{C835DF63-2335-4946-B343-186E556C4FEC}</ProjectGuid>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}      
</ProjectTypeGuids>
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
<RootNamespace>ProcessorTest</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>ProcessorTest</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<SilverlightVersion>$(TargetFrameworkVersion)</SilverlightVersion>
<TargetFrameworkProfile>WindowsPhone71</TargetFrameworkProfile>
<TargetFrameworkIdentifier>Silverlight</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
<SilverlightApplication>true</SilverlightApplication>
<SupportedCultures>
</SupportedCultures>
<XapOutputs>true</XapOutputs>
<GenerateSilverlightManifest>true</GenerateSilverlightManifest>
<XapFilename>ProcessorTest.xap</XapFilename>
<SilverlightManifestTemplate>Properties\AppManifest.xml</SilverlightManifestTemplate>
<SilverlightAppEntry>ProcessorTest.App</SilverlightAppEntry>
<ValidateXaml>true</ValidateXaml>
<ThrowErrorsInValidation>true</ThrowErrorsInValidation>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>Bin\Debug</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE;WP8</DefineConstants>
<NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
<NoConfig>true</NoConfig>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>Bin\Release</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE;SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE</DefineConstants>
<NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
<NoConfig>true</NoConfig>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Phone" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Phone.Interop" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows" />
<Reference Include="system" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Net" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="mscorlib.extensions" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="..\Appli2\MainPage.xaml.cs">
  <Link>MainPage.xaml.cs</Link>
  <DependentUpon>MainPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="..\Appli2\Page2.xaml.cs">
  <Link>Page2.xaml.cs</Link>
  <DependentUpon>Page2.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</ApplicationDefinition>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="Properties\AppManifest.xml" />
<None Include="Properties\WMAppManifest.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="ApplicationIcon.png">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Content Include="Background.png">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Content Include="SplashScreenImage.jpg" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Page Include="..\Appli2\MainPage.xaml">
  <Link>MainPage.xaml</Link>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
<Page Include="..\Appli2\Page2.xaml">
  <Link>Page2.xaml</Link>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\Silverlight for Phone\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Silverlight.$(TargetFrameworkProfile).Overrides.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\Silverlight for Phone\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" />
 <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
   Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
</Target>
-->
<PropertyGroup>
<MarkupCompilePass1DependsOn>
  $(CompileXamlDependsOn)
  PreprocessXaml;
</MarkupCompilePass1DependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="PreprocessXaml">
<!-- Run the preprocessor on every page that is added to the project as link. The processed file will be saved at the link position. -->
<!--<Exec Condition="('%(Page.Link)' != '')" Command="XamlPreprocessor.exe &quot;%(Page.FullPath)&quot; &quot;%(Page.Link)&quot;"/>-->
<PreprocessorTask Symbols="$(DefineConstants)" File="%(Page.FullPath)" OutName="%(Page.Link)" Condition="('%(Page.Link)' != '')" />
<Copy SourceFiles="%(Page.Link)" DestinationFolder="C:\Users\Louis\Desktop\temp\" />
<ItemGroup>
  <ProcessedPages Include="@(Page->'%(Link)')" />
  <!-- Remove the original (linked) pages so that they are not compiled. -->
  <Page Remove="@(Page)" Condition="('%(Page.Link)' != '')" />
  <!-- Include the processed pages instead. -->
  <Page Include="@(ProcessedPages)" />
</ItemGroup>
</Target>
```